# Maintaining local asset cache

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resources

I'm writing a GUI remoting client where the server defines and executes screen and a small GUI application visualizes this on the client. I know this sounds a lot like a website and there will be a web client to this system, but for now I'm focusing on the WPF client implementation.

Part of this system is that I need to synchronize assets between the server and the client. The server has all assets store in a `.zip` file or as a directory structure on the file system; I haven't decided yet. These assets may change: assets may be added, removed or modified. These modifications need to be synchronized with the client.

**The problem I have is how to store these assets on the client.** I have come up with the following requirements:

- Assets are keyed by path like keys (e.g. `Images/Icons/16/add.png`);
- A CRC32 must be maintained per asset to detect chagnes;
- There will be roughly 100 to 200 assets;
- Size of the assets will range between 1 KB and 500 KB (only one or two); medium size is 8 KB; mostly `.png` image files;
- Since loaded assets will be cached in memory, retrieval doesn't have to be super fast;
- Since assets don't change often, updating the local cache doesn't have to be super fast.

**I have thought up the following approaches:**

- **Files on disc.** This has the following advantages:

  - Easy to implement;
  - Fast update and retrieval;

  And the following disadvantages:

  - Many files "somewhere" on disc;
  - Not possible to store meta data (CRC32);
- **Storing files in a `.zip` file.** This has the following advantages:

  - Well defined storage mechanism with good .NET support;
  - Maintains a CRC32 for me (I believe);

  And the following disadvantages:

  - Update and retrieval of random files is relatively slow (I believe);
  - Not possible to store extra metadata (don't know if I'm going to need this though);
- **Storing files in an SQLite database.** This has the following advantages:

  - Well defined storage mechanism with good .NET support;
  - Allows all kinds of metadata to be stored;
  - Fast update and retrieval of random files;

  And the following disadvantages:

  - May be completely overkill;
  - I'm worried about binary support with SQLite.

**My question is 1. am I overlooking an obvious alternative and/or 2. what approach would be the best.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Went for the KISS approach: just downloading the entire resource file to the client.**

Resource libraries won't get that big, 1 MB to 2 MB. Entire `.zip` file can be checked for changes with a single hash and updated only when changed. Since this won't happen often (at most once a month), this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go with the SQLLite (or MySql, which is open source and free).

In my experience, even small apps have a way of growing into large apps and you'll be glad you used the correct technology, even if it's overkill at the beginning.

Comment: The entire idea behind this client is to have the absolute minimum of functionality. It's like a minimal browser or a TTY client (putty) and the install needs to be kept to an absolute minimum (like 1MB with no dependencies). It's a requirement that it doesn't grow into a large application.

Comment: Oh I see.  You could also look into installing the MS Access runtime.  That is a pretty small footprint that gives a decent relational database.  Not sure if that would push you over 1mb or not.